# Pattern for constraining a type to another type

Tags: haskell, types

I know the title isn't great, so I want to just give a specific example. I have a tree-like structure, modeling a test suite:

```
data Metadata = Metadata { id :: Id, disabled :: Bool }
data Node =
    Suite { metadata :: Metadata, config :: Config, children :: [Node] }
    Test { metadata :: Metadata, code :: string }
```

So basically, we have `Suite`s, which themselves could own other test `Suite`s, or `Test`s. This is really quite similar to a `Tree` definition (with parent `Tree`s and terminal `Leaf`s). So far nothing too crazy, except for I've left out other details from the constructors (I used a hypothetical `Config` type for the `Suite` constructor, since the details of that aren't pertinent to this question, except to demonstrate that the two constructors are actually significantly different so you wouldn't want a directly recursive structure `Node = Node { stuff :: Stuff, children: Maybe [Node] }`

Now, I have a type that *relates* to this type. Specifically, as the tests are running, I keep track of their respective statuses:

```
Status =
   Waiting |
   Skipped { dueTo :: Id } |
   Failure { reason :: Reason } |
   Success { duration :: int }
```

The `Test`s (and `Suite`s) could at any given moment be in any one of these states (there are more statuses left out since I do not believe them to be relevant). . I store the states in a hash table of sorts from `Id` to `Status`: `Table Id Status`.

The problem arrises that, while `Skipped` and `Waiting` are actually totally fine for both `Suite` and `Test`, `Failure` and `Success` actually want to store slightly different data depending on for which they are. Without getting into the weeds of the specific information, say we want the `Failure` for `Suites` to store the failed child `Id`'s to avoid repeatedly re-calculating this (in our case there is actual non-generative data stored). One option is to just break it up into two `Status`es:

```
   ...
   TestFailure { reason :: Reason } |
   SuiteFailure { failedChildren :: [Id] } |
   ...
```

This isn't great though because you need something like `isFailure = Status -> Bool` since there are TWO failures, and because we can't guarantee that `TestFailure`s will be associated with `Test`s in our hash table. We can solve the first problem by splitting out the internal info into a separate type:

```
data FailureInfo =
   TestInfo { reason :: Reason } |
   SuiteInfo { failedChildren :: [Id], otherStuff :: Whatever }

data Status =
   ...
   Failure { info :: FailureInfo }
   ...
```

This is certainly better, but there is still the issue that I can't guarantee that a `Failure { TestInfo }` is only associated with a `Test`. This is the crux of my question: given a type with multiple constructors, how can a variate a supporting type on those constructors in a way that I get the maximum support from the compiler.

If you imagine temporarily that `Suite` and `Test` were actually distinct types (instead of merely constructors of one type), I would maybe want a type parameter `Status a`, and a hash table mapping from `a` to `Status a` (but this would also not completely answer the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single hashmap it's going to be difficult to statically guarantee that tests are not mapped to suite-failures or vice versa. 
The ideas you already have are pretty much what you can do unless you want to have two different ID-types and require each lookup to specify if a test or suite is being queried for status.

If I may suggest a more drastic change: How about getting rid of the hashtable and storing the tests and statuses in the same structure?

Something like:

```
-- s is suite data, t is test data
data Node s t =
    Suite { metadata :: Metadata, children :: [Node s t], suiteStuff :: s }
    Test { metadata :: Metadata, testStuff :: t } 

Status f =
   Waiting |
   Skipped { dueTo :: Id } |
   Failure { failStuff :: f } |
   Success { duration :: int }

-- Like the old node type, containing test cases
type TestTree = Node Config String

-- A status tree contains IO actions for retrieving the current status of tests/testsuites
type StatusTree = Node (IO (Status [Id])) (IO (Status Reason))

-- Running tests
startRunning :: TestTree -> IO StatusTree
```

Depending on how you typically traverse the statuses, this could work quite nicely. Of course you can still have a HashMap (or two hashmaps) underneath it all if you want (e.g. `Table Id (Status (Either [ID] Reason))`) and the IO-actions in the tree are just lookups. Or you could just have an `IORef` for each suite/test.

Writing or deriving a `Functor` instance for `Node` may be very useful.

Comment: Thanks this is a great answer! I am going to try the more generic Node definition you provided.